# How to get javascript object value?

Tags: javascript, object

I have this static filter :

```
let self = this;
return self.datagrid.filter(
  function(data) {
    return data.statut.toLowerCase().includes(self.search.toLowerCase())
    ||
    data.etape.toLowerCase().includes(self.search.toLowerCase())
    ||
    data.code.toLowerCase().includes(self.search.toLowerCase());
});
```

I want to make it dynamic like this:

```
let self = this;
return self.datagrid.filter(
  function(data) {
    let query = "";
    for (let i = 1; i < self.colgrid.length; i++) {
      if (i < self.colgrid.length - 1) {
        query += "data." + self.colgrid[i].field + ".toLowerCase().includes(self.search.toLowerCase()) || ";
      } else {
        query += "data." + self.colgrid[i].field + ".toLowerCase().includes(self.search.toLowerCase())";
    }
  }
  return eval(query);
});
```

But it returns :
`Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with a style guide, your code is showing a few problems, for example the use of eval is considered bad practice as it can lead to security breaches.
Using a style guide could be very helpful:

[AirBnb Styleguide guidelines](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)

As for your question it is not clear what you are trying to achieve because in the second code there are properties like field which you are not using in the first one.

But for accessing dynamic properties Javascript gives you that possibility by using brackets, so instead of concatenating your query in a string with dots as you do here:

```
query += "data." + self.colgrid[i].field + ".toLowerCase().includes(self.search.toLowerCase())";
```

you could do something like this instead:

```
const query = [];
   ...
query.push(data[self.colgrid[i]].field.toLowerCase().includes(self.search.toLowerCase());
```